# RPi3 Watchdog monitoring a directory instead of a file

Tags: pi-3b+, watchdog

I have a C++ application that permanently runs on a Raspberry Pi 3 and might occasionally freeze. It writes logfiles using Boost log and a good indication of a freeze is the absence of logging output for a certain period of time.

Now and easiest solution would be to have the RPi's hardware watchdog monitor the logfile and eventually do a restart. Unfortunately, I'm using log rotation resulting in changing file names for the current log file. And seemingly, the watchdog config file at `/etc/watchdog.conf` only takes a single file name to monitor.

Is there any possibility to have the watchdog monitor the whole log directory? Monitoring the most recent logfile would also be a possibility, but due to log rotation I can only provide the watchdog with a filename pattern here.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a directory name instead of a file name: according to the man page, watchdog will try to `stat` the file, and that should work for directories too. Note that directory is only considered "changed" when files are created/removed in it, so the triggering period should be long enough for the rotation to occur.

If that's not OK, you will have to write your own "heartbeat" code. I would start with a script which checks the log files and reboots if they didn't change, and run that script from a `cron` job. Watchdog is only really needed to catch cases where your whole system is unresponsive, not just one app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it with a watchdog, but not with the RPi's one.

My app is running as a systemd service, and seemingly systemd also offers a watchdog mechanism. I've created the following service description

```
[Unit]
Description=DroneBox

[Service]
Type=simple

WorkingDirectory=...
ExecStart=...

Restart=always
RestartSec=30

# Watchdog-Signal.
WatchdogSec=900

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The line `WatchdogSec=900` makes the watchdog restart my app if it doesn't send a keepalive signal every 900 seconds latest.
The app now must notify the watchdog after initialization to start the counter and regularly send keepalive signals. In C++, this can be done using the systemd library by

```
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
...
sd_notify(0, "READY=1"); // Start watchdog
...
sd_notify(0, "WATCHDOG=1"); // Send keepalive signal
```

See e.g. [this link](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/cc/13148-applying-c-running-programs-with-systemd.html?start=2) for a good usage description of that library.

I'm not calling the Boost logging commands directly, but through a wrapper class, so I can easily exchange logger implementations.

```
#include "Logger.h"
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/from_stream.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>

Logger* Logger::pInstance = nullptr;

Logger::Logger()
{

    boost::log::register_simple_filter_factory<boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char>("Severity");
    boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory< boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");
    boost::log::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", boost::log::attributes::local_clock());

    std::string a_cwd = std::string(getcwd(NULL, 0));
    boost::log::add_common_attributes();
    std::ifstream file(a_cwd + "/log.ini");
    boost::log::init_from_stream(file);

}

Logger::~Logger()
{
}

Logger* Logger::instance()
{
    if (pInstance == nullptr) {
        pInstance = new Logger();
    }
    return pInstance;
}

void Logger::logInfo(std::string message)
{
    sd_notify(0, "WATCHDOG=1");
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << message;
}

void Logger::logDebug(std::string message)
{
    sd_notify(0, "WATCHDOG=1");
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << message;
}

void Logger::logWarn(std::string message)
{
    sd_notify(0, "WATCHDOG=1");
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << message;
}

void Logger::logError(std::string message)
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << message;
}

void Logger::logFatal(std::string message)
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << message;
}
```

By calling `sd_notify(0, "WATCHDOG=1")` with every logging command, I've reached my original goal.